# onclick() gives error: ReferenceError: LoadAjax is not defined at HTMLInputElement.onclick

Tags: javascript, html, events, onclick, referenceerror

Here is my code which does not work at all.

**HTML code:**

```js
<input type="button" value="Click Here" onclick="LoadAjax()"/>
```

**JS code:**

```js
function LoadAjax(){ 

  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    request = new XMLHttpRequest()
  } else {
    request = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP')
  }

  //request.open('GET', 'data.json')
   request.open('GET', 'http://localhost:20301/api/values')
  request.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (request.readyState === 4 && request.status === 200) {
      var items = JSON.parse(request.responseText)
      console.log(items);
      var output = '<ul>'
      
      for (var key in items) {
        console.log(items[key])
        output += '<li>' + items[key].Name + ' | ' + items[key].Family + '</li>'
      }

      output += '</ul>'
      document.getElementById('update').innerHTML = output
    }
  }
  request.send()
}
```

Comment: [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Comment: The function has to be available before it is referenced in the markup. Move the `<script>` tag into the `<head>` of the site.

Answer (score 0):

If you have got both in the HTML file, do it this way. It will prevent to call the function before it's loaded by binding the "onClick" after it is loading:

```
<input type="button" value="Click Here" id="myID">
<script>

     function LoadAjax(){ 
    
      if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        request = new XMLHttpRequest()
      } else {
        request = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP')
      }
    
      //request.open('GET', 'data.json')
       request.open('GET', 'http://localhost:20301/api/values')
      request.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (request.readyState === 4 && request.status === 200) {
          var items = JSON.parse(request.responseText)
          console.log(items);
          
    
          var output = '<ul>'
    
          for (var key in items) {
            console.log(items[key])
            output += '<li>' + items[key].Name + ' | ' + items[key].Family + '</li>'
          }
    
          output += '</ul>'
          document.getElementById('update').innerHTML = output
        }
      }
      request.send()
    }
    myElement = document.getElementById("myID");
    myElement.onclick = function() { LoadAjax(); return false; }

</script>
```

If you have got it in separate files, use this (attention! Inside the js file you DO NOT use the HTML "script" tag.

my.html:

```
[...]
<input type="button" value="Click Here" id="myID">
[...]
<script src="my.js"></script>
[...]
```

my.js:

```
     function LoadAjax(){ 
    
      if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        request = new XMLHttpRequest()
      } else {
        request = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP')
      }
    
      //request.open('GET', 'data.json')
       request.open('GET', 'http://localhost:20301/api/values')
      request.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (request.readyState === 4 && request.status === 200) {
          var items = JSON.parse(request.responseText)
          console.log(items);
          
    
          var output = '<ul>'
    
          for (var key in items) {
            console.log(items[key])
            output += '<li>' + items[key].Name + ' | ' + items[key].Family + '</li>'
          }
    
          output += '</ul>'
          document.getElementById('update').innerHTML = output
        }
      }
      request.send()
    }
    myElement = document.getElementById("myID");
    myElement.onclick = function() { LoadAjax(); return false; }
```